# Exception (task was canceled) when uploading app packages

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

When I was uploading my custom app packages, it would take nearly 2 minutes and then display System. AggregateException which says “a task was canceled”.

However, I have tried uploading some packages with smaller size and they could be uploaded successfully.

Is there a time limit for uploading app packages? Or do you know what’s the reason for this exception?

Comment: Checking with the development team and will let you know their feedback ...

Comment: There is a timeout of 3 mins... From where are you uploading your app package exactly? Did you try to first upload it to S3 and then to the service. It will be much faster this way

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I just recorded the time for uploading the app package and it almost took 1 minute and 50 seconds and then display the exception...Guess it doesn’t exceed the time limit... By the way, I’m using the client in this sample https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-.net-custom.activity.sample to upload app packages. I’m in Singapore :) Could you give me more information?

Comment: Hi @YouyouGao may I know the size of your package?

Comment: @Xiaodong Liang  
The packed size for the archive is 7.6MB.

Comment: @YouyouGao, thank you, then it looks not related something of package limitation. We are still checking with engineer team. probably you could try with my test harness? https://github.com/xiaodongliang/Forge-Design-Automation-Training/tree/master/Net . it is working well at my side (China) no readme yet with the test harness, but it might not be difficult to you to run it. let me know if you need help on this sample  xiaodong.liang At autodesk.com

Comment: @YouyouGao, will you still need help with this question? can my test sample help you to find the issue? Please let us know if the issue has not solved.

Comment: @Xiaoxong Liang Thanks for your advise. I’m guessing the exception is because of unstable internet cause previously when I included 5 dependencies in my package, it would take a long time for uploading and the exception would occurred, but this morning I could uploaded all the nine dependencies with a fast speed. However, the result is unknown command. One problem is that I can’t find the group name of my command, do you have some advise? Is it the reason cause unknown command? By the way, will all the dependencies automatically included in my crx or Need I to add them by myself?